# Checking convergence of an integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

I was wondering if I could get a hint on checking the convergence of the following integral
$$\int_1^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}\right) \, dx $$
I managed to prove the it does not converge absolutely, but got stuck on checking if it converges conditionally. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could add your proof for the lack of absolute convergence?

Comment: I don't know how to add certain math expressions so I will explain the idea. I defined the function abs(sinx/sqrt(x)) and used the limit test on abs(f(x)). If I am not mistaken the limit is 1, so they both diverge. Is that correct?

Comment: From your comment I can't really say one way or another. You can look up MathJax tutorial here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/269624 it will come in handy later anyway

Comment: The integrand function is $\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\sin^2 x}{2x}+O(x^{-3/2})$, and while $x^{-3/2}$ is Lebesgue integrable and $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$ is conditionally convergent by Dirichlet's test, $$ \int_{1}^{M}\frac{\sin^2 x}{2x}\,dx \sim \frac{1}{4}\log(M)$$ as $M\to +\infty$, so the given integral *is not* convergent, either in the Lebesgue or improper-Riemann sense.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio   Why not just post this as an answer?

Comment: I don't really understand it, I think we haven't learned that in my course yet.. :(